# Turn a php form (page) into a pop up form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a php form which sends an email once filled in which could be accessed through a button on my website that redirects to that contact form page.

But I would like it to rather be a pop up form that they can fill in and then it fades away. For example, rather than clicking on the button and going to another page, I want the form to pop up inside the same page and fade away.

Could anyone give me a solution where I could create this kind of pop up form?

Thank you.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use JavaScript to be able to create such a pop up form.

Imaging you have this button :

`<button id="popup" onclick="div_show()">Click me</button>`

You would need to create a function as follow :

```
//Function To Display Popup
function div_show() {
document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "block";
}
```

Source : https://www.formget.com/how-to-create-pop-up-contact-form-using-javascript/